# Can I safely remove app.json in a ejected react-native project?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I have a react native project which I ejected and now I see I have config files(*app.json* and *package.json*) with lots of duplicate information, not to mention the underlying info contained in the iOS/android projects. Specifically I am talking about version, name, package name etc.

My question is do I need to keep both if I am not using the managed workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to notbrent from the Expo Team, it's exclusively used by `expo-updates` you can safely remove it if you don't plan to use it.

You can follow the thread [here](https://forums.expo.dev/t/is-app-json-app-config-js-still-required-after-ejecting-to-the-bare-workflow/51458/2)